Why is Airflow killing my on_failure_callback function from a DAG after 1min?
I defining a dag like
@dag(
    'some_dag',
    on_failure_callback=__handle_failure
)
def some_dag():
    ...

And the failure callback looks like this:
def __handle_failure(context):
    print('DagRun failed')
    time.sleep(100)
    print('Starting callback')
    """
        Stuff goes here
    """
    print('Callback ended')

Forcing my dag to fail and looking to the shceduler logs, I can see the first print, but not the second. If I reduce the sleep time to 50s, I can see the first and the second, but not the third (the stuff part takes a bit of time). If I completely remove the sleep, I can see all prints and check that __handle_failure did everything it had to. But in some cases where the stuff part takes especially long (I make it process a bigger file), it doesn't get to the end either. It seems like, after approx one minute, the process gets killed, but there's no log on the scheduler that shows it.
I've looked into the documentation to find anything about this, but found nothing. There's a dag parameter dagrun_timeout, but I haven't defined it so it shouldn't affect it, and I have tasks that take longer than the failure callback and get executed without any problem. Placing a sleep inside a task just works as expected. Defining the timeout to a higher number doesn't change a thing.
Why is this happening and how can I avoid it?
